# Passport/Express: Unable to Authenticate User after creating a New User on register

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, authentication, passport.js

I have a NodeJS/Express server running. I am using PassportJS from Authentication.

I have successfully created login capability. I am able to successfully login in a user that already exists in the server when it is started.

I am unable to successfully authenticate a new user. The user is created successfully, and passport authentication seems to go through. But when redirected and `isAuthenticated` is called. It returns false.

I have tried using exactly what I am using in the login auth. I have tried the simplest version of the passport auth. I have researched many SO answers and consulted the documentation

Current relevant code:

```js
passport.use(
  new localStrategy(
    { usernameField: "userName" },
    (userName, password, done) => {
      const userList = getUsersByUserName(userName);

      if (!userList[0]) {
        return done(null, false, {
          message: "Invalid Username or Password.\n",
        });
      }
      if (password !== userList[0].password) {
        return done(null, false, {
          message: "Invalid Username or Password.\n",
        });
      }

      return done(null, userList[0]);
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user: User, done) => {
  done(null, user.userID);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  const user = users[0].userID === id ? users[0] : false;
  done(null, user);
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (perr, user, info) => {
    if (info) {
      return res.send("Invalid Username or Password.");
    }
    if (perr) {
      return next(perr);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.redirect("/");
    }
    req.login(user, (lerr) => {
      if (lerr) {
        return next(lerr);
      }

      return res.send(user); // I am redirecting in the client code
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});

app.post("/register", (req, res, next) => {
  const userName = req.body.userName;
  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const cpassword = req.body.cpassword;

  if (!name) {
    return res.send("Please enter a Name");
  }
  if (!userName) {
    return res.send("Please enter a Username");
  }
  if (!email) {
    return res.send("Please enter an Email");
  }
  if (password !== cpassword) {
    return res.send("Passwords do not Match");
  }
  if (password.length < 4) {
    return res.send("Password must be at least 4 characters");
  }
  const userList: User[] = getUsersByUserName(userName);

  if (userList.length > 0) {
    return res.send("That username is already taken");
  }

  const newUser: User = {
    userID: uuid(),
    userName,
    password,
    email,
    name,
  };

  users.push(newUser);

  passport.authenticate("local", (perr, user, info) => {
    if (info || !user) {
      return res.send("Invalid Username or Password.");
    }
    if (perr) {
      return next(perr);
    }
    req.login(user, (lerr) => {
      if (lerr) {
        return next(lerr);
      }

      return res.send(user);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

```js
function isAuthenticated(req: any, res: any, next: any) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }

  return res.redirect("/");
}
```

When following the register passport auth. I am seeing results that would make me believe that the user should be authenticated. But when the user is redirected and the `isAuthenticated` is called. I receive false

`Update`

I am storing my sessions using `session-file-store`. The session is stored without the userID...

```
Logging in: {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"__lastAccess":1564192764406,"passport":{"user":"7fa35b71-8733-441e-afcd-ed68defa68bf"}}

Registering a new user: {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"__lastAccess":1564193852150,"passport":{}}
```

Comment: Is `getUsersByUserName(userName);` an asynchronous function that's being called synchronously?

Comment: It is a Synchronous function. I forgot to mention I am not hooked to a DB yet. So the users are stored locally. This is a side project. I wanted to get this working locally before moving to a DB

Answer (score 0):

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {

  const user = getUser(id as string);
  // const user = users[0].userID === id ? users[0] : false;
  done(null, user);
});
```

I was comparing the first user instead of finding the user using the id.... Big Fail.